# search by name in sql table - clustered indexing

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have table (`Products`) with column (`barcode PK`, `name`) I want efficient way to search by `name`, I read the clustered indexing speed the search? But how can I use it, can anyone explain clustered indexing?

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index directs SQL to physically store the data in the ordinal position of the index value. So if you have 5 rows with the same clustered value, they are all store sequentially (a heap table) next to one another. SQL does not need to scan an entire table to find matching values. You may lose minor INSERT performance, but certain SELECT queries that use the clustered index field will be dramatically faster.

If you ran this query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ClusteredIndexField = 'A'
```

SQL knows that all rows with an "A" value in the clustered field are all together. Once it finds the first matching row, it iterates the next rows. SQL can reliably know not to search any longer as it knows no more rows can possibly match the condition.

http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/03/29/clustered-indexes-advantages-disadvantages/

Comment: hmm.. so in my table `Products` simply I create index for name column, then if I use the query `SELECT` with condition `WHERE name ="Nutella"` the search will be efficient ?

Comment: Yes it should be. The pros and cons of index types, and whether or not an index is even helpful, is a deep subject. I encourage you to read up on this. But in general, this seems like a very good use case and will absolutely make things better. A Clustered Index is often referred to as a "silver bullet" and you only get one of them, but I think you are on the right track.